# XML namespace extension causes NAMESPACE_ERR in SOAP envelope

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, xalan

I have a SOAP envelope into which I am adding a response payload. I have define the namespaces:

```
xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint.com/1.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

in the response element.

In the *custom.nsendpoint.com/1.1* XSD have 2 elements that are extended from a base type:

```
  <xs:complexType name="Contact">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        A Contact
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="EmailAddress" type="s:ContactEmailAddress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
      <xs:element name="Address" type="s:Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CompanyContact">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Company Contact type
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Contact">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Name" type="s:CompanyName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
          <xs:element name="Type" type="s:CompanyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
          <xs:element name="Size" type="s:CompanySize" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PersonContact">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        Person Contact type
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Contact">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Title" type="s:PersonTitle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element name="FirstName" type="s:PersonFirstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="MiddleName" type="s:PersonMiddleName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
          <xs:element name="LastName" type="s:PersonLastName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

So I define a type like this:

```
<Contact xsi:type="PersonContact">
    <EmailAddress>foo.bar@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <Street xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint/contacts/1.1">10 New Street</Street>
        <Suburb xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint/contacts/1.1">Hobboken</Suburb>
        <City xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint/contacts/1.1">New York</City>
        <State xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint/contacts/1.1">New York</State>
        <PostCode xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint/contacts/1.1">000000</PostCode>
        <Country xmlns="http://custom.nsendpoint/contacts/1.1">USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Title>MR</Title>
    <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Jebus</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Bar</LastName>
</Contact>
```

To my knowledge this is the correct way to define a namespace extension but I get the following error message when I try to do a Spring JAXP [transform](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/xml/transform/TransformerObjectSupport.html#transform%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result) on the document:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
```

When I drill into the `transform` method logic I see it fails on the `traverse` method invoked on a `org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker` object, saying:

```
Method threw 'org.xml.sax.SAXException' exception
```

If I remove the *xsi:* prefix on the contact type the error message goes away.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.